# How to use temp table twice in dynamic query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic

I want to use a table variable in a dynamic query.

So I do like below:

```
SET @sql_query = N'

SELECT *
from #temptable
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql_query;
```

and it works very well.

However, I need to use the temp table twice like below:

```
SET @sql_query = N'

SELECT *
from #temptable tm1
where tm1.column1 in (select column2 from #tttable)
 OR tm1.column3 in (select column4 from #tttable)
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql_query;
```

but, it doesn't work.

If I remove one condition, it works fine.

So I guess that temp table can only used in one time.

How can I solve it?

---

Edit: This works fine:

```
SET @sql_query = N'

SELECT *
from #temptable tm1
where tm1.column1 in (select column2 from #tttable)
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql_query;
```

and this also work fine:

```
SET @sql_query = N'

SELECT *
from #temptable tm1
where tm1.column3 in (select column4 from #tttable)
'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql_query;
```

I want to say that the condition doesn't have a problem.

Now if I the code in question the error message is that:

> The syntax near '#tt' is incorrect.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. Thank you, i fix it.

Comment: What does "not work" mean?  Do you get an error or something else?

Comment: does  "but it doesn't work" means you get not data or it means you have an error message?  to me, it's not and issue with the temp table, but with the condition. Please post more information (values, structure of the table, ....)

Comment: Your query shows two different temp tables `#temptable` and `#tttable`, and your code doesn't show you creating the temp tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff. it have an error message, and error meaasage was changed each time.

Comment: @MLeblanc. And error message doesn't contain meaning full things. for example.. (something wrong near 'FR') but, it change each time.

Comment: @Dale K. since the code maybe longer, so i omit them.

Comment: The problem is you haven't provided a [mre] and without that we can't help you. Nothing seems wrong with the query you provided... so you need to make it a complete example that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Dale K. Ok.. thank you for your reply. my question is that, in dynamic query, one temp table can be used twice? (in my code, #tttable was used two times.)

Comment: Sure you can - no problem. If you are getting errors something is wrong with you code.

Comment: @Dale K. Thank you. i will trace it.. if i can't find, i will create new question with reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I solve the problem...
the size of "@sql_query" was the problem..
temp table can be used twice like below:

Thank you.

```
create table #temp1
(
  column1 varchar(10)
)

create table #temp2
(
  column2 varchar(10)
  ,column3 varchar(10)
  ,column4 varchar(10)
)

create table #temp3
(
  column5 varchar(10)
)

insert into #temp1 values('aaa')

insert into #temp2 values('aaa', 'bbb1', 'ccc')
insert into #temp2 values('aaa', 'bbb2', 'ccc')
insert into #temp2 values('aaa2', 'bbb3', 'ccc2')
insert into #temp2 values('aaa2', 'bbb4', 'ccc2')

insert into #temp3 values('aaa')
insert into #temp3 values('aaa2')

    declare @sql_query NVARCHAR(1000) = N'
    select *, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY temp2.column2 order by temp2.column3 desc ) as MAXRank
    from #temp2 temp2
    join #temp3 temp3
    on temp2.column2 = temp3.column5
    and 
    (
        (column2 in (select column1 from #temp1) and column4 = temp3.column5)       
        OR (column2 not in (select column1 from #temp1) and column4 != temp3.column5)
        OR column3 = ''bbb1''
    )
    '


    EXEC sp_executesql @sql_query;

DROP TABLE #temp1
DROP TABLE #temp2
DROP TABLE #temp3
```